# Programmatically select options in dependent selects

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to programmatically select options in dependent select boxes, because the user has the opportunity to do a search and I want to auto-fill the form if that's the case.  This wouldn't ordinarily be difficult, but the issue seems to be that the dependent select receives a lot of data and, thus, takes 1-2 seconds to load and it's not getting set like it should, so I tried to use a callback on the change trigger.  But now, it's not doing anything within that function.  Please help!  (And tell me if I'm being ridiculous and should be doing this a completely different way.)

Here is my JSFiddle so you see the basic idea of what I'm doing (it's NOT working in the fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/jenborn/24Kpv/1/

```
   $("select#firstselect").val('abc').trigger("change", true, [function(){
     console.log("initial value and change DONE");
     console.log('Jen is awesome');
     $("select#secondselect").val('123');
     console.log($("select#secondselect").val()); 
   }]);
```

The dependent select is populated as such:

```
$.getJSON("/cat_dropdowns.php",{parent_id: $(this).val(), required: '1', ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
  var options = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + j[i].value + '">' + j[i].text + '</option>';
  }

var next_select = ++this_select;
  $("select#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row).html(options);
  Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#' + ctrl + next_select + "_"  + row), true);
  Foundation.libs.forms.assemble();
});
```

Once the dependent select has been populated dynamically from the parent select's onChange function, I need to programmatically select the correct option based on the user's search.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to do. You have two selects, options of the 2nd are dynamically loaded (by what means?) based on 1st value, and then? what are you trying to do? tell some more.

Comment: Here is the crux of the problem: the dependent select, which is being populated onChange of the parent select, is not getting set programmatically like it should be.  It IS being populated, but not set, and I'm not sure why since the surrounding console.log lines are working properly.  And setting the correct value needs to wait until the Change event is triggered, I think, which is why I tried to use a callback, but I'm not sure that was correct and is probably why it's bombing.

Comment: So if I recall correctly: you have two selects, 2nd is dynamically populated according to what user chooses in 1st, and one of the options of 2nd should be selected as well according to 1st?

Comment: It was because of a completely different issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006922/jquery-functions-not-behaving-logically

Comment: This was resolved through a totally different issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006922/jquery-functions-not-behaving-logically

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>loder</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="#">
            Team 1:
            <select id="team1" name="team1" onchange="team1select()">
            </select>
            Team 2:
            <select id="team2" name="team2" onchange="team2select()" disabled="disabled">
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            getTeam1();
            getTeam2();

        });
        function getTeam1() {
            var json_array = ['India', 'Pakistan', 'Australiya'];
            var default_option1 = "<option value=''>Select Team 1</option>";
            $("#team1").append(default_option1);
            $.each(json_array, function (key, val) {
                var option = "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
                $("#team1").append(option);
            });
        }
        function getTeam2() {
            var json_array = ['India', 'Pakistan', 'Australiya'];
            var default_option2 = "<option value=''>Select Team 2</option>";
            $("#team2").append(default_option2);
            $.each(json_array, function (key, val) {
                var option = "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
                $("#team2").append(option);
            });
        }

        function team1select() {
            $("#team2").empty();
            getTeam2();
            var dropdown1_selected = $("#team1").val();
            $("#team2 [value='" + dropdown1_selected + "']").remove();
            $("#team2").prop('disabled',false);
        }
        function team2select() {
            var dropdown2_selected = $("#team2").val();
            $("#team1 [value='" + dropdown2_selected + "']").remove();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```