# jquery functions not behaving logically

Tags: jquery

Weird function behavior.  I'm working in a parent function, here is the relevant portion:

```
   $("select#" + prefix + "1_" + num).val(smart_cat_data['cat_lvl2_id']);
     Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($("select#" + prefix + "1_" + num), true);
     console.log("initial value and change DONE");
     $.when(populateDep.call($("select#" + prefix + "1_" + num)),
     console.log("loading dependent select DONE"),
     console.log("setting " + prefix + "2_" + num + " TO: " + smart_cat_data['cat_lvl3_id'])
     ).then(function(x){
     $("#" + prefix + "2_" + num + " > option").each(function() {
         console.log(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
     });

     $("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num).val(smart_cat_data['cat_lvl3_id']);
     Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num), true);
     console.log($("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num).val());
     });
```

which calls:

```
function populateDep(){
console.log('populateDep');
     id_in_str = $(this).attr('id');
console.log('PROCESSING:' + id_in_str);
     var ctrl = id_in_str.slice(0,3); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
     var this_select = parseInt(id_in_str.slice(3,4), 10); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
     var row = id_in_str.slice(5);

    $.getJSON("/cat_dropdowns",{parent_id: $(this).val(), required: '1', ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].value + '">' + j[i].text + '</option>';
      }

    var next_select = ++this_select;
      $("select#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row).html(options);

                     $("#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row + " > option").each(function() {
                         console.log('populateDep: ' + this.text + ' ' + this.value);
                     });
      Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#' + ctrl + next_select + "_"  + row), true);
      Foundation.libs.forms.assemble();
console.log('this should be after the selects but before the end');
    });
console.log('populateDep DONE');
}
```

But for some reason, console.logs from populateDep are printing AFTER it claims to be finished.  And it's messing with the options of my select and not allowing me to auto-select like I need to.  Is this a newbie thing?  Am I missing something?  I'm including an image of firebug, because I thought that would be easiest.

[image]

Updated populateDep:

```
function populateDep(){
console.log('populateDep');
     id_in_str = $(this).attr('id');
console.log('PROCESSING:' + id_in_str);
     var ctrl = id_in_str.slice(0,3); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
     var this_select = parseInt(id_in_str.slice(3,4), 10); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
     var row = id_in_str.slice(5);

    $.when($.getJSON("/cat_dropdowns",{parent_id: $(this).val(), required: '1', ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].value + '">' + j[i].text + '</option>';
      }

    })).then(function(options){
    console.log('starting then');
    var next_select = ++this_select;
      $("select#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row).html(options);

     $("#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row + " > option").each(function() {
         console.log('populateDep: ' + this.text + ' ' + this.value);
     });
      Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#' + ctrl + next_select + "_"  + row), true);
      Foundation.libs.forms.assemble();
      console.log('this should be after the selects but before the end');

    });
console.log('populateDep DONE');
}
```

Now, it appears not to be populating the select at all.  Please note that $.getJSON has a callback already so I'm pretty confused as to what is going on.

Comment: you need to pass promise objects to `$.when` which you are not doing that could the reason for problem

Comment: Also, the `console.log` should execute before the asynchronous call back function. Basically the callback gets fired after the task `$.getJSON` completes, but being asynchronous, `$.getJSON` lets the rest of your code run while it goes off and does its thing.

Comment: @JasonNichols Sorry, I don't understand.  I want everything that happens after $.getJSON within populateDep to happen after the $.getJSON is complete.  Should I wrap it in a when/then?

Comment: @ArunPJohny so populateDep.call($("select#" + prefix + "1_" + num)) isn't an adequate deferred?  I'm wanting it to complete the function call before moving on

Comment: or just put it in your callback. Basically any asynchronous function branches off the main thread, but the main thread continues. So whatever comes after declaring the asynchronous call back will execute as if the asynchronous function weren't there.

Comment: you need to return a promise object from `populateDep`, it looks like you need to return the promise of the `$.post` request. Also need to remove the console.log statements passed to `$.when`

Comment: In this case where is no need to use `$.when` as you are dealing with a single promise...

Comment: You can have a look at this piece I made... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XF47a/1/)....

Comment: Also note that `populateDep DONE` will get printed before `this should be after the selects but before the end` because you are using an asynchronous request

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm doing a happy dance.  It's working!!!!  Thank you so much for your help!  If you add your fiddle as an actual answer, I'll give you the credit

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have a quick followup question.  I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XF47a/2/
When I click on $("#existing_to_sl"), it's not currently setting $("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num).val(data['cat_lvl3_id']);  like it should.  Thoughts?

Comment: what is the value of `data['cat_lvl3_id']`

Comment: also whether the dropdown is populated correctly?

Comment: can you add the following console statements after setting the value `$("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num).val(data['cat_lvl3_id']);
   
   var $select = $("#" + prefix + "2_" + num);
   console.log($select.get(), $select.find('option').get(), data['cat_lvl3_id'])`

Comment: @ArunPJohny the first item's data['cat_lvl3_id'] is 375.  It will always be an integer.  On the page, I can see it auto-filling the select.  The problem is that in setSelect, for some reason it isn't seeing that value and inserting a new row like it should be (This instance has 8 rows of selects that I want it to auto-fill). The console statements you requested print after "all done" Here's a link to an image from firebug: [link](http://dev.homebrewninja.com/images/firebug2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a quite a few problems in your approach as I explained in the comments.

Try

```
$("select#" + prefix + "1_" + num).val(smart_cat_data['cat_lvl2_id']);
Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($("select#" + prefix + "1_" + num), true);
console.log("initial value and change DONE");

populateDep.call($("select#" + prefix + "1_" + num)).done(function (x) {
    $("#" + prefix + "2_" + num + " > option").each(function () {
        console.log(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
    });

    $("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num).val(smart_cat_data['cat_lvl3_id']);
    Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num), true);
    console.log($("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num).val());
});

function populateDep() {
    console.log('populateDep');
    id_in_str = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('PROCESSING:' + id_in_str);
    var ctrl = id_in_str.slice(0, 3); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
    var this_select = parseInt(id_in_str.slice(3, 4), 10); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
    var row = id_in_str.slice(5);

    return $.getJSON("/cat_dropdowns", {
        parent_id: $(this).val(),
        required: '1',
        ajax: 'true'
    }, function (j) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].value + '">' + j[i].text + '</option>';
        }

        var next_select = ++this_select;
        $("select#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row).html(options);

        $("#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row + " > option").each(function () {
            console.log('populateDep: ' + this.text + ' ' + this.value);
        });
        Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#' + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row), true);
        Foundation.libs.forms.assemble();
        console.log('this should be after the selects but before the end');
    });
}
```